# Dynamically creating table inside form with JS, will load blank page before I submit form to Laravel backend

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms

I have this form inside a blade.php file, that contains a table. I am adding rows to this table dynamically by pressing on "Add" button, which adds the selected option (with a JS function). If I enter a "Name" in the first input tag, and then Add a selected option to the table, the page reloads and is blank without even giving me the chance to submit the form. What is going on?? Has anybody ever had a similar problem? Thanks for precious help!

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/groups/create') }}">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
            @error('name')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Add user</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="custom-select" id="chooseUserSelect" name="user_id">
                <option value="0">Choose...</option> 
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="addUserToGroupButton" disabled>Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="usersInGroupTable">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create group</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

tbody tag is empty because I am creating rows with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it was a simple error! The "Add" button was acting like a submit button, so the solution was simply to add `type="button"` and voilà! Kinda weird it was acting as a  submit button without specifying the type...

Comment: Sorry, disregard that other comment. A button inside a `<form>` will act as a submit by default if you don't specify the type :) Rule of thumb is **always** specify the type to avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I thought the ```type="submit"``` was discriminant for submitting a form..